# Permissions for group/other different than owner's permission

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I know it doesn't make much sense, but can I give the group a permission to write while the owner only has read permission?

Also, what is the outcome, if the owner will try to write (let's say he's part of the group)?

Comment: Just try it: `chmod 066 somefile`, and then try to read (as owner). Or `chmod 466 somefile`, and then try to write (as owner).

Comment: ok, cool. Future readers - It only checks the matching bits, i.e if you're the owner it will only look on the owner bits...